# Press key after making phone call Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-call

I'm making an App which call a service provider and press 1 after a certain amount of time and press again something and so on.

I've made call through "`Intent.ACTION_CALL`" as I can't write my own Call maker.

My Question is "How do I press something after I have fired an intent?"

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you want to enter a number after a pause you enter a number after "," like this: 1-555-555-1234,77 This will call the number and enter 77 after a certain pause. So you enter this number in your intent and don't worry about clicking after firing the intent.